# PowerBI Report Builder - Number Formatting Issue (negative rounded zeroes)

Tags: reporting-services, number-formatting, powerbi-paginated-reports

I am stuck trying to format rounded zeroes in PowerBI Report Builder.

If the number rounds to zero but is less than zero then I want to show the zero in parenthesis, however I can't seem to do this.

ie; -0.1, formatted to 0 dp shows as 0, not (0)

I tried using standard formatting approach...  #,##0;(#,##0);'-'
I expected this to show (0) as per MS Excel.

I also experimented with using expressions but could not seem to get the desired outcome.

P.S: I have set font colour using an expression so I know the values are definitely below zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit untidy, but this should work..

Set the format expression to

```
=IIF(
    Fields!num.Value >=0, 
    "#,0;(#,0);""0""",
    "(#,0);(#,0)"
    )
```

Here's the result (in the last column)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alan, I tried something similar to this.  This solves my zero bracket problem but creates a new problem, now any non zero negative numbers show as -(x) not just (x).

Comment: I've edited the answer, hopefully this is now what you want

Comment: That seems perfect, thanks, really appreciated.